# ngTable with icon outside of table

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I would want the trash bin icon to appear outside of the table. Right now its inside the table and upon hovering, the trashbin icon would appear before pushing the content to the right. How do i make it such that the trash bin icon would appear outside of the table beside each content?

**JS**

```
$scope.tdemo = {};
// table dataset
$scope.myDataset = [
   {
        name: 'eeee',
        lastname: 'dada',

   },
   {
       name: 'abc',
       lastname: 'kfc',

   }      
];

$scope.hoverIn = function () {
    this.hoverEdit = true;
};

$scope.hoverOut = function () {
    this.hoverEdit = false;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<table ng-table="twinTableParams" class="table hover">
    <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="trans in $data" ng-mouseover="hoverIn()" 
        ng-mouseleave="hoverOut()">
            <td>
               <span ng-show="hoverEdit" class="animate-show">
               <a><i class="fi-trash"></i></a>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td ng-model="name" title="'name'">{{trans.name}}</td>
            <td ng-model="lastname" title="'lastname'">{{trans.lastname}}</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this to `$scope`. You can use `this` if you are using controller As syntax

```
 $scope.hoverEdit=[];
 $scope.hoverIn = function (index) {
                    $scope.hoverEdit[index] = true;
                };

                $scope.hoverOut = function (index) {
                    $scope.hoverEdit[index] = false;
                };
```

And change your HTML to the following

```
 <table ng-table="twinTableParams" class="table hover">
        <tbody>

            <tr ng-repeat="trans in $data" ng-mouseover="hoverIn($index)" ng-mouseleave="hoverOut($index)">

                <td ng-model="name" title="'name'">

                    {{trans.name}}
                </td>
                <td ng-model="lastname" title="'lastname'">
                    {{trans.lastname}}
                </td>


            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<div ng-repeat="trans in $data">
    <span ng-show="hoverEdit[$index]" class="animate-show" >
                       <a>
                         <i class="fi-trash"></i>
                       </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what you are doing is just moving the trash icon appearing on the right hand side. I want it to be on the left hand side and completely out of the table. Just Beside next to the table.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Without creating a plunker, I can't really help you much in the design aspect of the code. You have to create the div/span in such a way that it aligns with the rows(tr) of the table.

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that (I don't really understand what's the good UX for it). You can set this  as a float element and move it outside the table.